# What is the proper method of disinfecting a room exposed to feline URI?

Tags: cats, upper-respiratory-disease

We currently have one cat in our home. We recently fostered a kitten with an upper respiratory infection (URI) for roughly one week.

We were aware of the URI and we quarantined the kitten in a room during his stay, which ended about a week ago. We were also careful to wash thoroughly (and change clothes) after interacting with the kitten.

We have kept our cat out of the quarantine room since the kitten left.

The quarantine room contains some books shelves, some upholstered furniture, and an area rug.

**What is the best way to disinfect that room so we can open it to our cat?**

Comment: is your cat vaccsinated against feline herpes virus and feline calicivirus? this will lower the risk a lot,you can find more information here https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/feline-upper-respiratory-infection